# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error when data is `null`. I checked for `null` but still getting same error :

> Unable to get value of the property 'length'.

Below is my code.

```
success: function Success(data) {

                if (data) {

                    alert(data.post);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d[i].length; i++) {

                    }

                    $("[Id*=lblSuperVisorName]").html(data.d[i].SuperVisorName);

                    $("[Id*=lblmobileNo]").html(data.d[i].MobileNo);
                }
                else {


                    alert(data.post);
                }
            },
```

Checking to see if AJAX response is empty and other problems?

Comment: if condition is applicable only for data and not for the array/object (data.d[i]) inside it

Comment: so how i can check condition for array??

Comment: Post the mock-up data of the response

Comment: why you  have  $("[Id*=lblSuperVisorName]").html(data.d[i].SuperVisorName);

                    $("[Id*=lblmobileNo]").html(data.d[i].MobileNo); out side of for loop. var i will not be available there.

Comment: assigning value to lblmobileNo,lblSuperVisorName. I am getting values for both if for that persone have moblie no and supervisor name. Getting error if data is null . in this part  for (var i = 0; i < data.d[i].length; i++)

Comment: What is the structure of `data`? It looks like `data.d` is undefined or something

Comment: yes Jeremy its data is undefined..

Comment: Thanks Jeremy your question gave me hint :) found answer . i checked before for loop if (data.d.length !=0) ..  from data.d.length  i am getting length of data. so i can found data is null or not ..  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calculate the lenght of passed data by dada.d.lenght  if lenth is greater than zero then assign value to lable.

success: function Success(data) {
                     var len = data.d.length;
                    if (len != 0) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d[i].length; i++) {
                        }                 
                        $("[Id*=lblmobileNo]").html(data.d[i].MobileNo);
                        $("[Id*=lbluid_nmbr]").html(data.d[i].uid_nmbr);
                     }
```